# Ngif Condition to Search Array of Object

Tags: angular

I tried implementing a message if no search is found. The ngif condition works a bit fine. However, the problem here is that when the page loads it shows the message even before the customer clicks on the search button. The condition set here if the filteredBook length == 0 then the message "No Book search found"  Below is HTML code

```
<div class="card" *ngIf="!showspinner && filteredBook.length==0">

<div class="card-header notification py-3">
  <span class="font-weight-bold text-white">No book search found</span>
</div>

 </div>
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5hcwj - check this may helps you

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `filteredBook` with `undefined`, which is falsy.

Then when you click the button you receive a value for `filteredBook`, which is truthy, even if the length of the array is null.

You can do something like this:

```
<div *ngIf="!filteredBook">
 <!--pending-->
<div>
<div *ngIf="filteredBook">
 <!--loaded-->
 <div *ngIf="filteredBook.length">
  <!--show the content-->
 <div>
 <div *ngIf="!filteredBook.length">
  <!--no book search found-->
 <div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5hcwj)

```
 filteredBook: any;     // right now it is falsy  value
```

Declare a variable, your api response set it to  `filteredBook`

```
api.getBooks((resp) => {
  this.filteredBook = resp;
});
```

In template file - add one more condition against  `filteredBook`

```
<div class="card" *ngIf="!showspinner && filteredBook && filteredBook.length==0">

<div class="card-header notification py-3">
  <span class="font-weight-bold text-white">No book search found</span>
</div>

 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Saurabh. Find the answer very useful

Comment: @Augustine glad to help you!